# Is this a stable way to show/hide a div and a certain "id" using jQuery or could I use a better approach?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two containers, one is a page of link blocks and a have another container hidden. In the hidden container there is articles that link to the main pages link blocks. So user "clicks" LINK ONE in the main container which then hides the main container, shows the originally hidden container and ONLY displays the id article it is linked to. There is then a "back to library" button which will take you back to the main container and set everything back to square one. I have it working at the moment but I'm not sure if it is the right way to achieve this? I know there is no right or wrong and if it works, it works but just wondering for peace of mind. Thanks :)

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/mDDDD/pen/ZEObRdR

HTML:

```
<div class="container--article-blocks" id="articleBlocks">
    <div class="article-block">
        <a class="show-article" href="#articleOne">LINK ONE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="article-block">
        <a class="show-article" href="#articleTwo">LINK TWO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="article-block">
        <a class="show-article" href="#articleThree">LINK THREE</a>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- articles -->
<div class="container--articles" id="articles" style="display: none;">
    <a href="back-to-library" class="back-to-library">back to Library</a>
    <div id="articleOne" class="article-block-articles">One</div>
    <div id="articleTwo" class="article-block-articles">Two</div>
    <div id="articleThree" class="article-block-articles">Three</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.show-article').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).show().siblings('div').hide();
   
  

    $('#articleBlocks').fadeOut();

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#articles').fadeIn();
    }, 500);
  });

  $('.back-to-library').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#articles').fadeOut();

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#articleBlocks').fadeIn();
    }, 500);
  });
```

Comment: If you want to provide a working example, use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead of a link to CodePen.

Comment: As you say, there is no right or wrong, so any answer will be an opinion, and questions which are primarily opinion-based are off-topic.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the callback for `.fadeOut()` to then call `.fadeIn()`. Nothing wrong with that you did, this will just ensure the item is faded out before executing further code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show-article').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).show().siblings('div').hide();
    $('#articleBlocks').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('#articles').fadeIn();
    });
  });

  $('.back-to-library').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#articles').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('#articleBlocks').fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container--article-blocks" id="articleBlocks">
  <div class="article-block">
    <a class="show-article" href="#articleOne">LINK ONE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="article-block">
    <a class="show-article" href="#articleTwo">LINK TWO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="article-block">
    <a class="show-article" href="#articleThree">LINK THREE</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- articles -->
<div class="container--articles" id="articles" style="display: none;">
  <a href="back-to-library" class="back-to-library">back to Library</a>
  <div id="articleOne" class="article-block-articles">One</div>
  <div id="articleTwo" class="article-block-articles">Two</div>
  <div id="articleThree" class="article-block-articles">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `visibility: hidden;` after an event!

Actual example

`document.getElementById("XXX").style.visibility = "hidden";`

But actually, your project is just fine!
For more info, go here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp
This explains the HTML DOM visibility property!

Comment: I don't think `style` is a valid CSS style. Do you mean `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`? That's what the jQuery `.hide()` method does.

Comment: `visibility` is not usually what you want. The space for the element is reserved even when the element is hidden, so you get a blank area.

Comment: So? In @hendy0817's case, it is fine!